# Match string having period, brackets and number in PHP

Tags: php

I want to make regex for a string having period , number and braces but can't figure out how to do that. here is string

```
SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.ID
```

i am using preg_match() but it doesn't match the above string. Help me out.

Comment: what is your expected output on this ?

Comment: Please show ```what``` you have tried so far.

Comment: basically i have an array which output result is like this [21] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.ID=20     [22] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Image[0].FilePath=/IntelliStorage/mnt/0-21625-0-2-1-1:11852.jpg     [23] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Image[0].Length=11852     [24] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Name=babar 
i have applied foreach loop. where i place a condition `if (preg_match("[0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Name=", array_value)) { echo "match" }

Answer (score 0):

I would use this pattern:

```regex
^\w+(?:\[\d+\])?(?:\.\w+(?:\[\d+\])?)*$
```

This pattern matches a word followed by optional `[num]` term.  Then, zero or more of dot followed by the preceding can follow.

PHP script:

```php
$input = "SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.ID";
if (preg_match("/^\w+(?:\[\d+\])?(?:\.\w+(?:\[\d+\])?)*$/", $input)) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
else {
    echo "NO MATCH";
}
```

Comment: i want to match exact same string. basically i have a variable which outputs "SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.ID=21" .. i want to match till "SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.ID=" and i dont know how to do that. preg_match() is not working on it.

Comment: No idea what this comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: basically i have an array which output result is like this
`[21] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.ID=20
    [22] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Image[0].FilePath=/IntelliStorage/mnt/0-21625-0-2-1-1:11852.jpg
    [23] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Image[0].Length=11852
    [24] => [0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Name=babar`
i have applied foreach loop. where i place a condition  
`if (preg_match("[0].SummaryNew[0].Value.Candidates[0].Person.Name=", array_value)) {
echo "match"
}